# Apple Mach-O linker error:library not found for -lBolts clang: error:

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying go to compile this app "https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore".but I have an error

> Ld
>   /Users/mavericmax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-hgscvoaueijbrwfuqfsdkjaxcpmv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse\
>   Store.app/Parse\ Store normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/mavericmax/Downloads/ParseStore-master
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk
>   -L/Users/mavericmax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-hgscvoaueijbrwfuqfsdkjaxcpmv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/mavericmax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-hgscvoaueijbrwfuqfsdkjaxcpmv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/mavericmax/Downloads/ParseStore-master -F\"/Users/mavericmax/Downloads/ParseStore-master/Store/Vendor\" -F/Users/mavericmax/Downloads/ParseStore-master/Store/Vendor -F/Users/mavericmax/Downloads/Bolts-iOS/ios -filelist /Users/mavericmax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-hgscvoaueijbrwfuqfsdkjaxcpmv/Build/Intermediates/Store.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Store.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Parse\
>   Store.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lBolts
>   -lMBProgressHUD -lParse -lParseUI -lStripe -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework
>   CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework
>   Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework
>   UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AddressBook
>   -weak_framework PassKit -weak_framework Social -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Social -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz.1.1.3 -lsqlite3
>   -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AdSupport -framework Accounts -framework AudioToolbox -framework UIKit -framework Bolts -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mavericmax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-hgscvoaueijbrwfuqfsdkjaxcpmv/Build/Intermediates/Store.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Store.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Parse\
>   Store_dependency_info.dat -o
>   /Users/mavericmax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-hgscvoaueijbrwfuqfsdkjaxcpmv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse\
>   Store.app/Parse\ Store
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F"/Users/mavericmax/Downloads/ParseStore-master/Store/Vendor"' ld:
>   library not found for -lBolts clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The directory 'vendor' exists, and I have additionally copied Bolts framework manually, clean and build(which failed).If anyone can point out what is wrong here, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Where is `libBolts.a` in your source tree?

Comment: I have updated my answer may be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.